# screen scraping using coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, screen-scraping, cfhttp

I am trying to screen scrape another application using the below code in Coldfusion.

```
 <cfhttp url="https://intra.att.com/itscmetrics/EM2/LTMR.cfm" method="get" username="uvwxyz" password="abcdef">  

 <cfhttpparam type="url" name="LTMX" value="Andre Fuetsch / Shelly K Lazzaro">

</cfhttp> 

  <cfset myDocument = cfhttp.fileContent>

<cfoutput>
  #myDocument#
</cfoutput>
```

Now when I run my cfm page, iam able to access the desitination page, with the above code. 
The destination page looks like below.

[image]

A part of the source code of this is as below.

```
<table border="1" width=99% style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <thead>
    <td colspan="12" class="drpmainheader1_2">LTM Detail Report for Andre Fuetsch / Shelly K Lazzaro</td>
    <tr align="center">
      <th class="ptitles">Liaison Name</th>
      <th class="ptitles">Application Acronym</th>
      <th class="ptitles">MOTS ID</th>
      <th class="ptitles">Priority</th> 
      <th class="ptitles">MC</th>
      <th class="ptitles">DR Exercise</th>
      <th class="ptitles">ARM/SRM Maintenance</th>
      <th class="ptitles">ARM/SRM Creation</th>             
      <th class="ptitles">Backup & Recovery Certification</th>
      <th class="ptitles">Interface Certification</th>
      <th class="ptitles">AIA Compliance</th>   
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetailleft">Lynette M Acosta</td>
    <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetailleft">AABA</td>
    <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail"><a href="http://ebiz.sbc.com/mots/detail.cfm?appl_id=9710" target="_blank" style="color:blue;">9710</a></td>
    <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail">5</td>
    <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail">NMC</td>
<td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail">Compliant</td> <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail">Compliant</td> <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail">Compliant</td> <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail">Compliant</td> <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail">Compliant</td> <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail">Compliant</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetailleft">Lynette M Acosta</td>
    <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetailleft">ABS RECON+</td>
    <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail"><a href="http://ebiz.sbc.com/mots/detail.cfm?appl_id=13999" target="_blank" style="color:blue;">13999</a></td>
    <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail">3</td>
    <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail">NMC</td>
<td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail">Compliant</td> <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail">Compliant</td> <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail">Compliant</td> <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail">Compliant</td> <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail">Compliant</td> <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail">Compliant</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

I am not good with regex in coldfusion, Can anyone please guide me or give me any starting points as to how to extract the data from the html table using Coldfusion? I do not have access to the DB. Hope this is clear.

Comment: I hope that's not a real username & password.

Comment: Being a former SBC/AT&T employee, this code above should be obfuscated... I recognize those names of the users and applications.

Answer (score 4):

Parsing HTML using regex?  You'll have more options if you use the jsoup HTML Parser w/ColdFusion. Jsoup uses jQuery-like DOM selectors and can quickly convert the HTML table data into arrays.

http://jsoup.org/

Here are some related articles & sample code:

- http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/4/6/jsoup-adds-jQuerylike-parsing-in-Java
- http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2358-Parsing-Traversing-And-Mutating-HTML-With-ColdFusion-And-jSoup.htm
- http://pastebin.com/U6A86mSi

Comment: thanks...i have not used any java objects from coldfusion before. How do i include the jsoup library from coldfusion. I downloaded the jsoup jar file, saved it in my directory, and I did this but i got an error.<cfset jsoup = createObject('java','org.jsoup.Jsoup')>Object Instantiation Exception.  
Class not found: org.jsoup.Jsoup  
any thoughts?

Comment: You might want to make a separate question on Serverfault.com for that question

Comment: That's _not_ a ServerFault question! It should ideally be a new question on StackOverflow, but the answer is to make sure you've put the JAR in the right directory (same `lib` dir as `cfusion.jar`) and restarted. In CF10 there's an admin setting to allow jars in other directories, and you can also use JavaLoader to target a specific jar.