# html parsing using jsoup and coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, jsoup

This is the continuation of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22668870/screen-scraping-using-coldfusion?noredirect=1#comment34542118_22668870). Below is the script I am trying to build to parse HTML which looks like the example below. I am getting the error ***Value must be initialised before use.*** Not able to attached the error.

I have to make a http call using jsoup where ***I need to provide username and password for the server login***. Is the below code right way to do it? I looked at the [Bennals blog](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2358-Parsing-Traversing-And-Mutating-HTML-With-ColdFusion-And-jSoup.htm) for html parsing using jsoup.

---

I have this in my Application.cfc

```
component {
  this.name = "jsoupTest";
  this.javaSettings = {loadPaths=["/jsoup/jsoup-1.7.3.jar"], loadColdFusionClassPath=true};
}
```

---

#### Example of the HTML to be parsed

*Note there are at least 5000 rows like below which need to be parsed and **extract only the TEXT from the TD**.*

```
<tbody>
        <tr>
        <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetailleft">Robert M Best Jr.</td>
        <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetailleft">AAI</td>
        <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail"><a href="http://ebiz.sbc.com/mots/detail.cfm?appl_id=7948" target="_blank" style="color:blue;">7948</a></td>
        <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail">1</td>
        <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail">MC</td>
    <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail">Compliant</td> <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail">Compliant</td> <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail">Compliant</td> <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail">Compliant</td> <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail">Compliant</td> <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail">Compliant</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetailleft">Robert M Best Jr.</td>
        <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetailleft">ABWS</td>
        <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail"><a href="http://ebiz.sbc.com/mots/detail.cfm?appl_id=4884" target="_blank" style="color:blue;">4884</a></td>
        <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail">4</td>
        <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail">NMC</td>
    <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail">Compliant</td> <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail">Compliant</td> <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail">Compliant</td> <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail">Compliant</td> <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail">Compliant</td> <td class="drpdetailtablerowdetail">Compliant</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
```

---

#### Updated Code to be used

```
     <cfhttp url="https://intra.att.com/itscmetrics/EM2/LTMR.cfm" method="get" username="abc" password="zxyr">  
 
 <cfhttpparam type="url" name="LTMX" value="Andre Fuetsch / Shelly K Lazzaro">
 
</cfhttp> 
 
 <cfset jsoup = createObject("java", "org.jsoup.Jsoup") />
<cfset document = jsoup.parse(myPage.filecontent) />

<cfset content = doc.getElementById("contentwrapper")>



<!--- Let's see what we got. --->
<cfdump var="#content#" />
```

[image]

Comment: _"Is the below code right way to do it."_ - does it work? If not, what error / unexpected result do you receive?

Comment: As a general note, you can use cfhttp to do the HTTP request and pass cfhttp.FileContent to jSoup. (That may or not be a better/worse option than doing HTTP via jSoup.)  Also, whilst your question was not bad, take a look at the [edits I just made](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22689787/revisions) to give it more structure/readability - specifically sub-titles help to label which code is which.

Comment: thanks Peter will keep in mind about the structure. Can you give me an example of how to pass the cfhttp.FileContect to jsoup?

Comment: It's just `dom = jsoupClass.parse(cfhttp.FileContent)`

Comment: Not sure where that error is coming from - maybe `writedump(dom.html())` to make sure the parsed HTML is what you're expecting. (Also, I didn't mean that the `var` should be removed, you still need that in front of the `dom` variable.)

Comment: I am getting a Variable DOM is undefined error now. I have the var keyword now. huh! thanks for your inputs!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the `.first().text()`.  Maybe `.first()` returned null somehow?  Everything looks good other than that line.

Comment: I have updated the code above, still i get the same error Varibale DOM id undefined....

Comment: dump `jSoupClass` to make sure the jsoup jar file is loaded correctly

Comment: The code you've posted creates `document` then tries to read `doc` - they should be the same variable.

Comment: Here's a simple example that works - https://gist.github.com/boughtonp/9930604 - I've ran that exact code on CF10 (10,0,11,285437). Try it without changes to confirm it works for you, then update one thing at a time to make it do what you need, and identify if/when any errors crop up.

Answer (score 0):

The myPage variable is being declared for the first time in your parse command.

I think you need to add **result="myPage"** to your cfhttp call.

```
<cfhttp result="myPage" url="https://intra.att.com/itscmetrics/EM2/LTMR.cfm" method="get" username="abc" password="zxyr">
```

Comment: Yes, but that would throw a different error. If you look at the error screen shot, the OP actually used the variable `cfhttp.filecontent` rather than `myPage`. If you run the code and dump each object, you can see the issue is [what @Henry suggested in the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22689787/html-parsing-using-jsoup-and-coldfusion#comment34577080_22689787). One of the method calls is returning `null` and that is what is causing the "..Value must be initialized before use..." error.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the reason it is not working is because you have not called the constructor on the Jsoup class.

Try changing this line

```
var jSoupClass = createObject( "java", "org.jsoup.Jsoup" ).init(); // note calling init calls the constructor for the Java class
```

Comment: I have dumped jSoupClass and tried the init method, it is not throwing any error but its just loading a blank page. When I view the source I see nothing....my jar file is in a folder names jsoup in the current directory...there is no lib or jars folder anywhere on the server i can see...

Comment: `createObject("java", "org.jsoup.Jsoup").parse(html)` is fine because `parse` is a `static` method

Answer (score -1):

Did you install your jar file correctly?

> ColdFusion searches for the objects in the following order:
>
> 1. The ColdFusion Java Dynamic Class Load directories:
> 2. Java archive (.jar) files in web_root/WEB-INF/lib
> 3. Class (.class) files in web_root/WEB-INF/classes

Quoted from : [About ColdFusion, Java, and J2EE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec14231-7fe5.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec14231-7fd3)

So copy your jar file to `web_root/WEB-INF/lib`, restart CF, and try again.